# Is there a way to know programmatically on which GPU our CUDA code is running?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I want to know on which GPU my CUDA kernel will run so that I could programmatically decide the optimal block size to use in order to maximise the performance of GPU implementation of any algorithm.

Comment: Yes, look at the `deviceQuery` sample code.

Comment: There are also APIs which do all the thinking on block size for you  You might not need to do what you had in mind at all.

Comment: Could you direct me which is that API? I am actually very new to CUDA programming so kind of unaware of many things.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the [deviceQuery](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#device-query) sample code demonstrates how to query the device for information such as the number of SMs which could be used to optimize kernel launch configuration.

In addition, CUDA provides an [occupancy API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#occupancy-calculator) which demonstrates how to construct thread block sizes that can yield highest occupancy.  There is a [sample code](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simpleoccupancy) also.

If you have 3 GPU devices, and you don't make use of the `cudaSetDevice()` API in your code to select a particular GPU, then CUDA will run your code on the first GPU enumerated by CUDA, which is the same as the first GPU displayed by the `deviceQuery` sample code.

Comment: Let's suppose I have 3 GPU devices to which my CPU is connected to and I actually wanted to know programmatically on which GPU my code would run by default. Or in the case where I want to select on which GPU to run depending on the size of my input. It would help if I am given some sample code to understand the same.